# R remove zeros based on criteria from other column

Tags: r

I want to create a new data set from existing one by removing rows from a variable in a data frame which have 0 as last values for each level of another variable. Example:

```
set.seed(100)

ID<-rep(1:20, each=5)
ID

var1<-sample(c(0, 1,2, 3), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6,0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
var1
df <- data.frame(ID,var1)
head(df,15)

   ID var1
1   1    0
2   1    3
3   1    0
4   1    3
5   1    1
6   2    0
7   2    0
8   2    1
9   2    0
10  2    0
11  3    1
12  3    0
13  3    2
14  3    0
15  3    0
```

Variable "ID" has 20 levels, for each level of ID I want to remove rows from data frame which end with 0. For example, last row of ID 1 in row 5 has value 1, therefore should be kept. 
We see that IDs 2 and 3 have 0 in the rows 9, 10, and 14, 15 for var1 and therefore should be removed.  If we look at ID 16, it has all 0 for var1 and should be completely removed from the new data frame. So just to clarify, 0 in var1 are fine, as long as they are not the last values for each level of ID, if they are, rows containing them should be removed regardless of how many rows are we talking about. 
The new data frame should look like this.

```
   ID var1
1   1    0
2   1    3
3   1    0
4   1    3
5   1    1
6   2    0
7   2    0
8   2    1
9   3    1
10  3    0
11  3    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!(var1 == 0 & cumsum(var1 != 0) == max(cumsum(var1 != 0))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID  var1
   <int> <int>
 1     1     0
 2     1     3
 3     1     0
 4     1     3
 5     1     1
 6     2     0
 7     2     0
 8     2     1
 9     3     1
10     3     0
11     3     2
```

Something seems wrong with your code for initial data frame, so I've just used the rows you have displayed, but should work anyway.

Comment: well, that was fast, and much simpler than I thought, it saved me the whole Friday of digging through huge excel tabels.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
DT[-DT[, {
    ri <- rleid(var1)
    .I[var1==0L & ri==ri[.N]]
}, ID]$V1]
```

output:

```
    ID var1
 1:  1    0
 2:  1    3
 3:  1    0
 4:  1    3
 5:  1    1
 6:  2    0
 7:  2    0
 8:  2    1
 9:  3    1
10:  3    0
11:  3    2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID var1
1    0
1    3
1    0
1    3
1    1
2    0
2    0
2    1
2    0
2    0
3    1
3    0
3    2
3    0
3    0")
```